# Taking the mode of a column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and am looking for a way to flag values in a column. I have a spreadsheet with 11 columns and 210 rows(each column would have a different mode) and want to highlight the numbers that do not match the mode for each column.

This is what I have now:

```
For n = 1 To 11

    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As Variant

    x = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, n).Value
    y = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(211, n).Value

    With Range(Cells(2, n), Cells(211, n)).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlNotEqual, WorksheetFunction.Mode(Range(x, y).Value))
        With .Font
            .Bold = True
            ColorIndex = 3
        End With
    End With

Next n
```

I am getting an error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

before I was getting an error on `worksheetfunction.mode` being undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `Range` object to the function not a value e.g.

```
WorksheetFunction.Mode_Sngl(Range("A1:A100"))
```

In your code you are currently passing the value of a cell by the looks of it and not a `Range`

Comment: Is there a way i could do this without a range? I have to calculate 11 columns and I was wondering if there was a way to do it w/o having to do it for column A,B,C,D etc individually.

Comment: From your code I'm not entirely sure what your ranges would be but you'd just build them up in your code so you're not doing them 'individually'